# Which then most sought where most might not be found,

Tags: relative-pronouns, quantifiers

What do the following "which" and "most" refer to?

> “I, measuring his affections by my own,
>   **which** then **most** sought where **most** might not be found,
>   being one too many by my weary self,
>   pursued my humor not pursuing his,
>   and gladly shunned who gladly fled from me.”

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: It's a poem (or at least poetic), and, so, is open to interpretation. There is likely also context that's missing. However, the following is possible: (1) *which* = my affections; (2) *most sought* = sought to the greatest degree; and (3) *most* = many people.

Comment: You think "most" in "most sought," is an adverb. If so, the relative clause would lack a main verb.

Comment: Not so. *My affections were most sought*.

Comment: What is the main verb in the relative clause?

Comment: I've already told you how I interpret it in my previous comment. If you're looking for a literal analysis, you will not find it. As I said, this is either poetry or poetic. It doesn't adhere to regular syntax.

Comment: Your interpretation would require a copular verb in the relative clause: which WERE then most sought where most might not be found

Comment: I see now that this is from Shakespeare. You will *never* succeed in forcing a 21st-century set of grammatical rules onto his 400-year-old poetic writing.

Comment: Is it generally the case that Shakespearian English requires no main verb, in this case, the copula, in the relative clause?

Comment: I think the two incidences of "most" have different meanings.  Here's how I see it (but I don't have much experience reading Shakespeare, so this might not be right): the first "most" means *primarily*; the second "most" means *most people*.  The thing that might be hanging you up is "where."  Try this: *my mood sought, more than anything, **a place where** nobody, or where few people, would be found.*

Comment: @aparente001 That's the right interpretation, which deserves to be an answer. Notice that the main verb in the relative clause there is *sought*--which is active, not passive. The subjetc of that verb is effectively *my affections* (the subject is actually technically the word *which*). The other interesting thing is that the relative clause incudes a free-relative (fused reative clause) which has no antecedent. In modern English, we would require *wherever* there instead of *where*.

Comment: @Araucaria - Okay, I posted an answer here.  I don't feel comfortable posting about this at ELU.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with poetic and outdated language. It may be better answered in https://literature.stackexchange.com or other sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the two incidences of "most" have different meanings. Here's how I see it (but I don't have much experience reading Shakespeare, so this might not be right): the first "most" means *primarily*; the second "most" means *most people*.

The thing that might be hanging you up is "where." Try this:

> my mood sought, more than anything, a place where nobody, or where few people, would be found.

Comment: I +1ed this post a while ago, but I thought it worth saying that this answer is very helpful (as well as being accurate, of course). It is obviously well-appreciated by readers and the OP too.